# jQuery UI .position() mouse event tracking with boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-position

I'm working on an image gallery within which I want to display all thumbnails in the same dimensions and have any overflow hidden, but onmouseover, the user is able to see the hidden portion of the thumbnail by moving their mouse within the thumbnails parent element, while the image tracks its movement.

jQuery UI:

```
$( '#targetElement' ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  $( "#position img" ).position({
    my: "center",
    of: event,
    collision: "none"
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#targetElement {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.positionDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.positionDiv img {
  min-height: 150px;
  max-width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="targetElement">
  <div class="positionDiv" id="position"><img src="http://er.pe/server/php/files/thumbnail/ill_09.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Please see <kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DdMgP/1/)**</kbd> for my current progress.

**What I'd like to do is set vertical boundaries so that the edges of the image cannot cross the vertical borders of its parent element.**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by setting boundaries within the borders of the images parent element because you are already using overflow hidden and most of the image is already cross the boundaries when dragged..  Maybe you can clarify what you want for me.

But here is a basic example of how you can have an image stay within boundaries using 'jquery-ui-draggable`.  Maybe you can modify this to accomplish your designs.

Here is an example:

```
   var right = 0;
    var bottom = 0;
    var top = 0;
    var left = 0;
    adjustment = 5;
    $( "img" ).draggable({
        start: function ( event, ui ) {
            bottom = $(this).parent().parent().height();
            right = $(this).parent().parent().width();
        },
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            if(ui.position.top <= top-adjustment)
                ui.position.top = top-adjustment;
            if(ui.position.left <= left-adjustment)
                ui.position.left = left-adjustment;
            console.log(ui.position.left);
            if(ui.position.left+$(this).width() >= right+adjustment)
                ui.position.left = right-$(this).width()+adjustment;
            if(ui.position.top+$(this).height() >= bottom+adjustment)
                ui.position.top = bottom-$(this).height()+adjustment;
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/B5f5M/

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/DdMgP/4/

Comment: Yes, sorry, it would only be the vertical borders on the sides of the parent element. Basically, you could just move the image up and down to see the rest of the image. I'll try out the jquery-ui-draggable code you posted and see if I can make that work. Thanks!

Comment: @Mute well here is an update with my code..  http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/DdMgP/3/  Are you wanting to be able to drag the image up down even when dragging outside of the box (like in my example) or just within the box?

Comment: Wow, that's great! Dragging outside the box like in your example is excellent. Now I just need to figure out a way to get it to stop when it reaches the edge of the image so that you cannot drag the image past top and bottom borders.

Comment: I briefly marked your reply as the answer, and I will again if no one has any solutions that use mouse position instead of draggable.

Comment: @Mute here is an update, stops when reaches edges.  http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/DdMgP/4/

Comment: You're my favorite person of today.